# IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable when trying to calculate AUC metrics with rdkit

Tags: python, auc, rdkit

I want to calculate the ROC curve with rdkit implementation:

rdkit.ML.Scoring.Scoring.CalcAUC(scores, col)

Determines the area under the ROC curve

code:

`import rdkit.ML.Scoring.Scoring`

`rdkit.ML.Scoring.Scoring.CalcAUC(scores, y)`

and I get the following error:

`IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`

my data:

`scores`

`array([32.336, 31.894, 31.74 , ..., -0.985, -1.629, -1.82 ])`

`y`

`array(['Inactive', 'Inactive', 'Inactive', ..., 'Inactive', 'Inactive','Inactive'], dtype=object)`

I do not know what's wrong.

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.ML.Scoring.Scoring.html)? Admittedly it is not great but the input should be: ***scores***: ordered list with descending similarity containing active/inactive information and ***col***: column index in scores where active/inactive information is stored. so something like `CalcAUC([(0.8, 1), (0.4, 0)], 1)`. If I were you I would use the scikit-learn implementation if possible.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I have been reading the rdkit documentation. But it has no examples

Answer (score 1):

```
from rdkit.ML.Scoring.Scoring import CalcAUC
scores = [32.336, 31.894, 31.74, 30., 20.]  # assume scores is sorted in descending order
y = ['Inactive', 'Inactive', 'Inactive', 'Active', 'Inactive']

label_map = {'Active': 1, 'Inactive': 0}
labels = [label_map[y_true] for y_true in y]
auc = CalcAUC(list(zip(scores, labels)), 1)
print('Area Under the ROC Curve:', auc)
```

As mentioned in the comment above. The documentation for `CalcAUC` and other metrics is [here](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.ML.Scoring.Scoring.html) but is pretty minimal.